# CMAKE ERROR with CLion

Tags: c, cmake, mingw, clion

I am a beginner in programming with C and I get this error code if i start a project on CLion:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\danie\CLionProjects\untitled2
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

g++.exe

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/danie/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/danie/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

[Finished]

What can I do to get it working?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems you have installed a C compiler (`gcc`), but not a C++ compiler (`g++`).

Comment: I am programming in C so i do not need a C++ Compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, CMake expects that project needs support for both C and C++. If your project needs only C, specify that in `project()` call:

```
project(<project-name> C)
```