# CLion can't detect CMake though CMake is installed and added to the Path

Tags: cmake, cygwin, clion

Here already have an answer of [CMAKE ERROR with CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012113/cmake-error-with-clion) but my question is different.

I installed **CLion** **2017.3.1** on Windows 8 64 bit. I already installed Cygwin 64 bit on my pc and **Cmake 3.9.6**. In the configuration window of the **CLion** it can't detect **Cmake**. I added **Cmake** to the path but **CLion** can't detect it. the errors are shown in following Fig.

[image]

After clicking on **Test CMake run finished with error**

It shows the following errors:-

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix 
Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a 
different build tool.

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Error code: 1
```

After installing **CMake** and adding it to the path why these errors are showing?
What is the meaning of these errors?
And how to fix these errors?

Plz help

Thank you

Comment: CMake is detected, but there were no C and C++ Compilers found. You need to install a compiler.

Comment: I installed Cygwin which comes with C and C++ compiler. So I have already installed C and C++ compiler

Comment: Input field titled with `Make` is intended for `make` program (which processes Makefiles), not for `cmake`, which you have already set above as "Bundled". Exactly this the error message say - "CMake was unable to find a build program ...". BTW, the second screenshot is better be converted into the **textual form**, this would allow searching the post by a text, and copy-pasting it into comments/answers.

Comment: So plz tell me what I have to do to make it error free?

Comment: @Tsyvarev That comment should probably have been an answer. @coding_ninza As was mentioned, you enter the path to you `make` executable (which is part of Cygwin, if you installed correctly) here.

Comment: I installed the make from Cygwin and that solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input field titled with `Make` is intended for `make` program (which processes Makefiles), not for `cmake` one. If you haven't `make` installed, install it.

See also this question: [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141608/cmake-make-program-not-found), which describes a meaning of the first error you have got.